# NullReferenceException in System.Web calling ServiceStack service with GetAsync from async ServiceStack service

Tags: c#, asynchronous, servicestack, nullreferenceexception

I have a ServiceStack service that uses async from top to bottom.  Below is a simplified example with all layers collapsed down to the Service Definition.

```
public async Task<ReadItemResponse> Get(Dto.ReadItem request)
{
    using (JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("http://someserver/itemservice"))
    {
        ReadItemResponse response = await client.GetAsync(new ReadItem
        {
            ItemNumber = request.ItemNumber
        });

        return new Dto.ReadItemResponse
        {
            Item = new Dto.Item
            {
                ItemNumber = response.Item.ItemNumber,
                ItemName = response.Item.ItemName
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I make numerous concurrent calls to the service, the above code causes a NullReferenceException in System.Web within 1 - 30 seconds.

```
System.Web.dll!System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(bool setImpersonationContext)
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(bool setImpersonationContext)
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.Util.ISyncContext.Enter()
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.SafeWrapCallback(System.Action action = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}})
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Util.SynchronizationHelper.QueueAsynchronous.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task _)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTaskSlot = Id = 1131, Status = Running, Method = "Void <QueueAsynchronous>b__0(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)")
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(bool bPreventDoubleExecution)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
[Native to Managed Transition]
```

If I replace the JsonServiceClient with an async call to something like System.Net.WebRequest (to retrieve and desalinize a JSON response), I never see the exception.

I have tried the JsvServiceClient with the same results.  I have tried to use the ConfigureAwait(false) with no success.  I have ensured that the web.config file is calling out:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

I have wrapped the body of the Get method with:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
```

which fixes the problem but drastically reduces the performance of the service.  The throughput goes from being able to process 100 concurrent requests in 2-3 seconds to something closer to 20-40 seconds.

I have also been able to make async database calls without encountering the NullReferenceException.

This definitely feels like an issue with the ServiceClient.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: If `JsonHttpClient` doesn't have issues why aren't you using it? There's also no need to create a new ServiceClient instance per request (i.e. you can just use a singleton instance) and there's no need to dispose it.

Comment: @mythz JsonHttpClient seems to have fixed the issue. Is there an inherent problem with the JsonServiceClient? What is the major difference?

Comment: @hedjos `JsonServiceClient` is based on .NET's `HttpWebRequest` whereas `JsonHttpClient` is based on Microsoft's HttpClient. But this NRE is happening within ASP.NET not the service client. Does this result in any Service Exceptions? If so please update the question with the full StackTrace of the Service Exception.

Comment: @mythz I added the full server stack trace to the post.  No Service Exception is thrown back to the client.  Eventually the client receives an exception indicating that "A task was canceled."  This only seems to happen when 2 or more concurrent requests are being made from the client to the service.

Comment: @hedjos I was after the Service Exception specifically, we don't have any control of an internal ASP.NET Exception nor does it tell us the source of the Exception. If you can put together a stand-alone repro which we can run locally (e.g on GitHub) we can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JsonHttpClient in place of the JsonServiceClient fixed the issue.